# How to print TCP Message from netcat in Go?

Tags: go, tcp, netcat

So I need to write a server in Go that prints messages from the following command:

```
echo "MESSAGE" | nc localhost 8080
```

It just has to print "MESSAGE" as a string on stdout. I can not use something else, it has to be this command. This is what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
  check(err)
  for {
    conn, err := ln.Accept()
    check(err)
    go handleConnection(conn)
  }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
  buf := make([]byte, 1024)
  reqLen, err := conn.Read(buf)
  fmt.Println(reqLen)
  check(err)
  // PRINT MESSAGE HERE
  conn.Write([]byte("Message received."))
  fmt.Println(conn.RemoteAddr().String())
  conn.Close()
}


func check(err error) {
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:" + err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
  }
}
```

I need a fmt.Println(???) where the comment // PRINT MESSAGE HERE is. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, you have other issues here too. When using an `io.Reader` you need to check the bytes read before the error, because you may get `io.EOF` from a valid Read (a one-size-fits-all error check function is usually a Go anti-pattern). The bytes read isn't the `reqLen`, it's just the number bytes read -- TCP doesn't have message framing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the message in quotes, you can use the `%q` format specifier (see the [fmt docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)).

You'll want to convert your buffer to a string and make sure you only use the part of the buffer that contains data (up to `reqLen`):

```
// buf[:reqLen] is a slice of the first reqLen bytes of buf.
// string(...) creates a string from a slice of bytes.
fmt.Printf("Message contents: %q\n", string(buf[:reqLen]))
```

This will print:

```
Message contents: "message\n"
```

The `\n` is inserted by `echo`. If you don't want it, run `echo -n ...`, or strip surrounding whitespace/newlines using [strings.TrimSpace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace).